# How to cumulatively calculate the percentile occupied by each element in a vector?

Tags: sql, dolphindb

For example, given a vector [2, 1, 6, 9, 7, 20, 0, 12]. Calculate the percentile of 2 in [2], 1 in the percentile of [2, 1], 6 in the percentile of [2, 1, 6], and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Including 0% and 100%, as follows:

```py
v = [2, 1, 6, 9, 7, 20, 0, 12]
cumrank(v) \ (cumcount(v)-1)
```